# Cannot connect to WAMP via LAN

Tags: wampserver, lan

I've WAMP server 2.1 installed on windows 8, and I'm trying to connect through LAN cable.

I've put it online, and changed apache2.conf settings to

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But still cannot connect to my server (tried through IP and machine name)

Comment: I guess it works locally but you want to access it from another computer, if that what I understand, try to disable your windows 8 firewall temporary and see if it works, if it does then try to make a rules for WAMP app, if that the case let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove any ip only listen port [image]

now start wamp server and click on its icon and click put online
also make sure firewall is allowing your port 80
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but now I get 403